# Fingerprint scan in app: Android

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-studio-2.3, android-fingerprint-api

I can use device fingerprint security for my app but I don't want to put a fingerprint security for the device and I want it for the app only.

By the use of this [Fingerprint](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-add-fingerprint-authentication-to-your-android-app-747304/),  I can use device fingerprint security for my app also but this doesn't meet my requirement.

**My actual requirement is-**

How can I create a custom fingerprint API for my android app only where the device is not having fingerprint lock?